# dplyr – get certain summary statics for multiple columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I want to create a summary statistics table for some summary functions for multiple variables. I've managed to do it using `summarise` and `across`, but I get a wide dataframe which is hard to read. Is there a better alternative (perhaps using `purrr`), or is there an easy way of reshaping the data?

Here is a reproducible example (the `funs` list contains additional functions I've created myself):

```
data <- as.data.frame(cbind(estimator1 = rnorm(3), 
                            estimator2 = runif(3)))
funs <- list(mean = mean, median = median)
```

If I use `summarise` and `across` I obtain:

```
estimator1_mean estimator1_median estimator2_mean estimator2_median
0.9506083          1.138536       0.5789924         0.7598719
```

What I would like to obtain is:

```
         estimator1 estimator2
mean     0.9506083  0.5789924        
median   1.138536   0.7598719
```

Comment: You could do: `tidyr::pivot_longer(df, everything(), names_sep = "_", names_to = c(".value", "metric"))` after `summarise`/`across`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pivot_longer()` with `.value` ("`.value`" indicates that the corresponding component of the column name defines the name of the output column containing the cell values, overriding `values_to` entirely, see [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html)), eg.

```
  library(dplyr)  
  data |>
    summarise(across(everything(), list(mean = mean, median = median, var = var))) |>
    tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = c(".value", "stats"), names_sep = "_")

  stats  estimator1 estimator2
  <chr>       <dbl>      <dbl>
1 mean        0.221    0.448  
2 median      0.110    0.429  
3 var         0.770    0.00288
```

Answer (score 2):

base R approach:

Using `sapply`:

`sapply(data, \(x) sapply(funs, \(f) f(x) ))` is applying a nested `sapply()` function to `data` and `funs`. For each element x of `data`, it applies each function f in `funs` to x using the inner `sapply()` function.

Both functions applied are anonymous functions defined with the `\(f)` syntax, which takes one argument `f`.

Having our given `funs <- list(mean = mean, median = median)`

The code `sapply(data, \(x) sapply(funs, \(f) f(x) ))` will apply `mean()` and `median()` to each element of `data` and return a matrix with the results:

```
sapply(data, \(x) sapply(funs, \(f) f(x) ))
```

```
       estimator1 estimator2
mean    0.3081365  0.4251447
median  0.2159416  0.3198206
```

Comment: thank you, this is also very clean. Could you please elaborate on the '\(x)' and the '\(f) f(x)'? I don't understand what is going on intuitively